# SQL Query Help - Selecting Only Non-Existent Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm aware this has been asked previously, but I just can't get it to work the way I need.

I have two identical tables in two different schemas. Let's call them table1 and table2. table1 is the master, it contains all entries... table2 should have duplicate data, but is missing some rows. I need to be able to select from table1 only those rows which are missing from table2, I've tried the following

```
select order, item from table1 where status = 133 and not exists 
(select order, item from table2 where status = 133)
```

But it always returns no results. I'm guessing I've just got the syntax wrong but can't think of the correct method

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not doing it right, here's how you should do it:

```
select order, item from table1 where status = 133 and not exists 
(select order, item from table2 where status = 133 and order = table1.order
and item=table1.item)
```

Or, another option (not tested):

```
(select order, item from table1 where status = 133)
except
(select order, item from table2 where status = 133)
```